# geometric description of set of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

A set of complex number:
$$S=\{ z\in \Bbb C : |z|=\lambda |z-1|\}$$

what's the geometric description?

I try to draw it ... which seems like a circle but cannot find the equation to describe it..

Comment: Why not writing $z=x+iy$ and see what happens? Note that, if $\lambda<0$, the set $S$ is empty, and is a point when $\lambda=0$. So, you could assume that $\lambda>0$ and work with the equivalent (but simpler) equation $|z|^2=\mu|z-1|^2$ (with $\mu=\lambda^2>0$).

Comment: by this I got $(1-\lambda^2)x^2 + (1-\lambda^2)y^2 = -2\lambda^2 x + 2\lambda^2$ and then could not be more simplify

Comment: It looks like to me like the equation of a circle or an ellipse (after completing the squares).

Comment: ye..mey be.$(x-\frac{\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2})^2 + y^2 = \frac{\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2}+(\frac{\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2})^2$...is it sensible?

Comment: Note that, since $|a-b|$ is the distance between points $a$ and $b$, the question has the following geometric meaning: What is the set of points which are farther from $0$ than $1$ by a factor of $\lambda$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a conformal mappings perspective. Let $w=\dfrac{z}{z-1}$. Then the equation in the question implies that 
$|w|=\dfrac{|z|}{|z-1|}=\lambda$. This is equivalent to $w=\lambda e^{i\phi}$ for  $\phi\in(-\pi,\pi)$; geometrically, these are circles of radius $\lambda$ in the complex $w$-plane. To see what this looks like in the complex $z$-plane, we solve for the inverse map  $z=\dfrac{w}{w-1}$. The image of $w=\lambda e^{i\phi}$ is then 
$$z(\phi)=\dfrac{\lambda e^{i\phi}}{\lambda e^{i\phi}-1}\cdot\dfrac{\lambda e^{-i\phi}-1}{\lambda e^{-i\phi}-1}=\dfrac{\lambda^2-\lambda e^{i\phi}}{1-2\lambda \cos\phi +\lambda^2}=\frac{(\lambda^2-\lambda \cos\phi)-i\lambda \sin\phi}{1-2\lambda\cos\phi +\lambda^2}$$

Note that, since we can identify this to a curve $(x(\phi),y(\phi))\in\mathbb{R}^2$, this is no longer a problem of complex variables but rather of identifying a parametrized curve.  (I'm having a spot of trouble of writing out said identification properly at the moment; I'll see if I can update soon.)

Comment: Nice solution!  The treatment of $\lambda$ can be improved a little bit. Because why $\lambda$ is now shown up in $z(\phi)$?

Comment: @Mike: Woops, you're right! Let me fix that.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $\lambda >0$. Then, $|z|=\lambda|z-1|$ is same as $|z|^2=(\lambda)^2|z-1|^2$. Writing $z=x+iy$ we have,

$x^2+y^2=(\lambda)^2((x-1)^2+y^2)$. Brings the $x's$ and the $y's$ to the same side.

For $\lambda < 0$, there is no solution.

For $\lambda=0$, the solution is just one point.

Comment: Please do not just give a down vote without indicating a reason.  I am also curious that why we can not find the solution $z(\phi)$ like given by Semiclassical.